# How to stop QComboBox/QSpinBox to emit signals when enabling/disabling them?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a small Qt plotting application and I am enabling/disabling widgets (combo/spin boxes) based on a "master" combo box. For example, say the master is `combo1`, which changes the entries in `combo2`, based on `currentIndex()`, enables/disables `spin1`, and sets a value for `spin1` if a certain entry in `combo1` is selected. There are more widgets than only these, though.

After the small discussion in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34914361#34914361) (and onwards), I used `Qt::QueuedConnection` with every `connect()`, but this didn't stop the re-enabled widgets to emit signals when re-enabled. This caused my many `connect()` to all be executed for all the re-enabled widgets, resulting in multiple plottings, which I want to avoid. As they are right now, (almost) all the widgets use `plot()` inside a `connect()`, so it's multiple signals to one slot.

My question: is there a way to prevent emitting the signals when the widgets are re-enabled? I could make `plot()` use some `bool` to check whether the plot has been executed and prevent further actions of the same type, but that would still cause the widgets to emit the signal and run `plot()`, even if the check will prevent the actual plotting, but that doesn't seem like the way to go. I would also prefer to avoid running `installEventFilter()`, or similar, as that would, most probably, slow down even more than the previous fix.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556687/prevent-firing-signals-in-qt

Comment: @Trevir Yes, that helped. But I had to choose `editingFinished()` for `QSpinBox` and `activated(int)` for `QComboBox`. If you make this an answer, I'll mark it down.

Comment: Glad, it helped, but i won't take credit for others work ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use disconnect before every connect to prevent multiple connections. Disconnecting a not connected slot is always allowed.

```
disconnect(spinbox1,...);
connect(spinbox1,...);
```

Blocking signals is also possible but I think you want the first solution.

From QtDocumentation:

bool QObject::blockSignals(bool block)
If block is true, signals emitted by this object are blocked (i.e., emitting a signal will not invoke anything connected to it). If block is false, no such blocking will occur.

Comment: This is also a solution, and it might compement the `editingFinished()` and `activated()` nicely, because I see now that, while it runs as intended, even a click in a spinbox, or on the plot area, will cause the signal to be emitted. I saw the `blockSignals()` before, but it doesn't seem to help here. If no other answer comes, I'll mark this one,and also Trevir's comment.

Answer (score 8):

Another option, already mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460061/how-to-stop-qcombobox-qspinbox-to-emit-signals-when-enabling-disabling-them#comment99369951_41461111), is to use [`QObject::blockSignals`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals):

```
combo1->blockSignals(true);
// do what ever you need
combo1->blockSignals(false);
```

I find it easier to use and read. Also, there are many situations where you simply don't know / handle the connections.

#### Update

Since Qt 5.3 you also have [`QSignalBlocker`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html), an exception-safe wrapper for `blockSignals` (internally it uses RAII to block signals in the constructor and restore them to their previous state on destruction):

```
{
  QSignalBlocker blocker{combo1}
  // do what ever you need
}
```